# Scatterplot y axis are separated

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a scatterplot with two types of plot. This is my code

```
data = np.genfromtxt("ca1_data/ridership.csv",
               delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
               dtype=[('Year','i4'),('Mode','U50'),('Ridership','U50')],
               missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
mrt = data[data['Mode']=='MRT']['Ridership'] 
bus = data[data['Mode']=='Bus']['Ridership']
labels =  np.arange(1995,2017)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(labels, bus, c='b', label='Bus Ridership')
ax1.scatter(labels, mrt,c='r', label='MRT Ridership')
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Average Daily Ridership')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');

plt.show()
```

It does create the scatterplot but it creates two scatterplot with different tick as shown in the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EW5y.jpg
I hope i have explained this clearly as English is not my first language. Thanks in advance!

Comment: dtype `U50` is a unicode string. If you plot strings they are considered as categories, just as if you plotted ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]. If you want numeric axes, use numbers when plotting.

Comment: Got it! I changed it to i4 and it works, thanks mate!